# Read input from popup window before executing entire main constructor

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a wpf application in which I have two wpf windows.  One is the main GUI and another is a popup which asks the user to input a number into a text box then press a button.

What I'm wondering is can I somehow call the popup window to be displayed in the main window constructor (this much I have with popup.Show()) and then read the input and wait until the user presses the button to continue on with the rest of the code in the constructor?

Basically once it gets to the popup.Show() line I want it to wait for the user to enter a value and press the button before the rest of the code after popup.Show() in the main window constructor is executed.

Answer (score 2):

Using `ShowDialog()` instead of `Show()` will cause the execution to pause until the popup is closed.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
popup.ShowDialog(); // Execution will halt here until the 'popup' is closed
```

I personally avoid using custom code inside window constuctor, I usually put this code on Window_Loaded

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick, but it will not show MainWindow until the Popup is closed.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnInitialized(EventArgs e)
    {
        var popup = new PopupWindow();
        popup.ShowDialog();

        base.OnInitialized(e);
    }
}
```

For the Popup

```
public partial class PopupWindow : Window
{
    public PopupWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Close();
    }
}
```